# Terraform: How to store a map in a single ssm-parameter and get back a value pair?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-parameter-store

let's assume i have a map like this:

```
variable "test_parameters" {
type = map
default = {
"A" = "subnet-73e35d3e",
"B" = "subnet-7e00d503",
"C" = "subnet-d9d446b2",
}
```

}

What is the terraform-code

1. to store the values of the map in a **single** aws_ssm_parameter ?
2. get a single value from the parameter like: B = subnet-7e00d503 or B:subnet-7e00d503 ?

Many thanks for help ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store it as json, and then get json back.

```
resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "foo" {
  name  = "myparam"
  type  = "String"
  value = jsonencode(var.test_parameters)
}
```

To read it:

```
data "aws_ssm_parameter" "foo" {
  name = "myparam"
}

# to use 

locals {
  myparam_values = jsondecode(data.aws_ssm_parameter.foo.value)
}
```

Comment: @RELiABLE No problem. Glad it worked out:-)